# The phpauth_session_cookie is not transmitted

Tags: php, apache

The phpauth_session_cookie is not transmitted
I have a problem with my app. I'm using PHPAuth and it doesn't create a phpauth_session_cookie for me (but PHPSESSID creates and passes it)
On local everything works as it should, the files are colonized on the server, they are identical. PHPAuth works fine, it returns the data from the database correctly after logging in

`$result = $this->auth->login($email, $password, $remember);`

I call the function

```
public function isUserLoggedIn() {
        return $this->auth->isLogged();
    }
```

Returns true, but once the redirect occurs, the specified phpauth_session_cookie is simply not transferred.

PHP 8.2, session.cookie_secure=0

I don't have that much experience with this, so I don't know exactly where to look to see what it's looking for.
Thanks for the advice

Comment: Is there actually no `Set-Cookie` header for this in the responses to the relevant requests? Or did your browser maybe _reject_ the cookie for some reason?

Comment: I tried chrome and edge, the problem is in both cases